# ELK bool query with match and prefix

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new in ELK. I have a problem with the followed search query:

```
curl --insecure -H "Authorization: ApiKey $ESAPIKEY" -X GET "https://localhost:9200/commsrch/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should" : [
        {"match" : {"cn" : "franc"}},
        {"prefix" : {"srt" : "99889300200"}}
      ]
     
    }
  }
}
'
```

I need to find all documents that satisfies the condition: OR field "cn" contains "franc" OR field "srt" starts with "99889300200".

Index mapping:

```
{
  "commsrch" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "addr" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "index" : false
        },
        "cn" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "compname"
        },
        "srn" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "srnsrt"
        },
        "srt" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "srnsrt"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index settings:

```
{
  "commsrch" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "routing" : {
          "allocation" : {
            "include" : {
              "_tier_preference" : "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "provided_name" : "commsrch",
        "creation_date" : "1675079141160",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "ngram_filter" : {
              "type" : "ngram",
              "min_gram" : "3",
              "max_gram" : "4"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "compname" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "stop",
                "ngram_filter"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
            },
            "srnsrt" : {
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "C15EXHnaTIq88JSYNt7GvA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "8060099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query works properly with just only one condition. If query has only "match" condition, results has properly documents count. If query has only "prefix" condition, results has properly documents count.

In case of two conditions "match" and "prefix", i see in result documents that corresponds only "prefix" condition.

In ELK docs can't find any limitation about mixing "prefix" and "match", but as i see some problem exists. Please help to find where is the problem.

Comment: Hi, Can you share documents count for only **match** only **prefix** and both of them.

Comment: Such a stupid problem.. I'm look just only to list of returned documents. If I look to documents count, everything work propelry! I'm forgot about result truncation to 10 documents. @MusabDogan thank you!

Comment: You're welcome I will share as answer:)

Answer (score 0):

In continue of experince I have one more problem.
Example:

1. Source data:
   1st document cn field: "put stone is done"
   2nd document cn field:: "job one or two"
2. Mapping and index settings the same as described in my first post
3. Request:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should" : [
        {"match" : {"cn" : "one"}},
        {"prefix" : {"cn" : "one"}}
      ]
     
    }
  }
}
'
```

As I understand, the high scores got first document, because it has more repeats of "one". But I need high scores for documents, that has at least one word in field "cn" started from string "one". I have experiments with query:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {"match": {"cn": "one"}},
            {
               "constant_score": {
                  "filter": {
                     "prefix": {
                        "cn": "one"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost": 100
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. What's wrong with my query?